# A tool which can in single click block all apps from using internet?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, internet, firewall

I will bring my laptop to my vacations and connect to the net via my mobile phone. the mobile transfer limit is limited to 200MB and I do not want to deplete it in one day.

I basically want that I manually allow my laptop's apps to use internet. If I use chat, I want it to be gtalk only, if I use the net, I want it to be Firefox only.

Is there a tool which I can use to temporarily block internet access for each app on my laptop and than manually allow/disallow apps from accessing the net?

I know I can do it via win7 firewall app, but it's too much work. I'd prefer if there is a tool like I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [BrowseControl](http://www.browsecontrol.com/application.htm)

Did it do the job?

> The Application Blocking feature lets organisations build a “blocked
>   list” of applications that users will no longer be able to launch from
>   their PCs. Using Browse Control, administrators can quickly and easily
>   block users from running dangerous, time-wasting or nuisance
>   applications such as KaZaa, instant-messaging programs or specific
>   games. BrowseControl is bullet proof since it uses the software’s
>   internal Windows name, so power users who decide to re-name their .exe
>   files to scam BrowseControl won’t make it.

Comment: I have to block each app separately? This is not the way I want to go

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to learn a little scripting you can set up those rules in windows firewall then enable or disable the rule by double clicking on a power-shell script.

Here is a script to get you started by toggling a firewall rule, you still need to have it enable/disable blocking all outgoing traffic you have not authorized.  Here is the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for controlling the firewall

```
#open firewall rules
$fw=New-object –comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2

#Toggle setting
$fwRdp = $fw.Rules | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'My Special firewall Rule'} | % {$_.Enabled = !$_.Enabled}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather have a finished app solution. I want to rest from the code for 15 days :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [ZoneAlarm](http://www.zonealarm.com/security/en-us/zonealarm-pc-security-free-firewall.htm) will do what you're looking for, but I must say I'm not exactly a fan of it. It's a little too heavy on its 'buy me!' approach.